# losing messages when calling http call with high concurrency

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

Hi I have stream definition like below.Where i pull file from s3 split line by line and  call http client and put to named channel.My transport is rabbit and prefetch is 10 and concurrency of http is 100 and running on 3 container and 1 admin.

```
stream aws-s3|custom processor| custom-http-client --url1=https://test1.com --url2=https://test1.com --filterAttribute=messageAttribute --httpMethod=POST --nonRetryErrorCodes=400,401,404,500 --charset=UTF-8 --replyTimeout=30000 --mapHeaders=Api-Key,Content-Type --requestTimeOut=30000  |processor> queue:testQueue
```

my http-config looks like below and using apache http client for connection pooling and multithreaded I am putting back to DLQ all very errors like  socket time out  and retrying it .All not retry error 50x i am passing to next module and writing to error queue.But after I call my external rest API i am losing messages.I am sending  around 220 k messages some time i get 200k messages some time i get all 220k and some time 210k its random.Not sure if i am doing anything wrong.I tried to increase the request time out socket time out.Till my processor before HTTP i get all message but after http client i see lesser messages in my named channel queue and nothing in error queue. But i am pretty sure messages are getting lost after calling http-client .This happens when there is  high load of data like million and 200k+  records for lesser   load like 500 to 1000 records i don't see this issue.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <!--    <context:property-placeholder location="${xd.module.config.location}\processor\${xd.module.name}\batch-http.properties"
         ignore-resource-not-found="true" local-override="true"/> -->

    <context:property-placeholder />

   <!-- logger changes start -->
    <channel-interceptor pattern="*" order="3">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="loggingChannel" />
        </beans:bean>
    </channel-interceptor>

    <logging-channel-adapter id="loggingChannel" log-full-message="true" level="ERROR"/>

<!-- logger changes end -->


    <header-filter input-channel="input"
                   output-channel="inputX" header-names="x-death"/>

    <service-activator input-channel="inputX" ref="gw" />

    <gateway id="gw" default-request-channel="toHttp" default-reply-timeout="0"  error-channel="errors" />

    <beans:bean id="inputfields" class="test.HTTPInputProperties">
        <beans:property name="nonRetryErrorCodes" value="${nonRetryErrorCodes}"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="responseInterceptor" class="test.ResponseInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="inputProperties" ref="inputfields" />
    </beans:bean>

    <chain input-channel="errors" output-channel="output">
        <!-- examine payload.cause (http status code etc) and decide whether
             to throw an exception or return the status code for sending to output -->
        <header-filter header-names="replyChannel, errorChannel" />
        <transformer ref="responseInterceptor"  />
    </chain>


    <int-http:outbound-gateway id='batch-http'  header-mapper="headerMapper"
                               request-channel='toHttp'
                               rest-template="batchRestTemplate"
                               url-expression="payload.contains('${filterAttribute}') ? '${url1}' : '${url2}'"  http-method="${httpMethod}"
                               expected-response-type='java.lang.String' charset='${charset}'
                               reply-timeout='${replyTimeout}' reply-channel='output'>
    </int-http:outbound-gateway>

    <beans:bean  id="batchHTTPConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" >
        <beans:constructor-arg index="0"  value="${charset}"/>
        <beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes" value = "application/json;UTF-8" />

    </beans:bean>

     <beans:bean  id="batchRestTemplate" class="testBatchRestTemplate" >
       <beans:constructor-arg name="requestTimeOut" value="${requestTimeOut}"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg name="maxConnectionPerRoute" value="${maxConnectionPerRoute}"/>
        <beans:constructor-arg name="totalMaxConnections" ref="${totalMaxConnections}"/>
</beans:bean>





<beans:bean id="headerMapper" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper"
            factory-method="outboundMapper">
<beans:property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="${mapHeaders}"/>
<beans:property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value=""/>
</beans:bean>

<channel id="output" />
<channel id="input" />
<channel id="inputX" />
<channel id="toHttp" />

        </beans:beans>



public class BatchRestTemplate  extends RestTemplate{

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
                .getLogger(BatchRestTemplate.class);

    private  static Integer requestTimeOut;

    private  static Integer totalMaxConnections;
    private  static Integer maxConnectionPerRoute;






    public BatchRestTemplate(Integer requestTimeOut,Integer totalMaxConnections,Integer maxConnectionPerRoute) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException  {
          super(createBatchHttpRequestFactory());
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters= new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        messageConverters.addAll(getMessageConverters());
        messageConverters.add(0,new StringHttpMessageConverter(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

    }

        private static ClientHttpRequestFactory createBatchHttpRequestFactory() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException  {

            CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory;

            SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory;

                socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                        SSLContext.getDefault(),
                        new String[] {"TLSv1"},
                        null,
                        SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
                    .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
                    .register("https", socketFactory)
                    .build();
            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);
            cm.setMaxTotal(250);
            cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(100);
            cm.closeExpiredConnections();



            RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(30000)
                    .setConnectionRequestTimeout(30000).setSocketTimeout(30000).build();



            httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).setConnectionManager(cm).build();


            httpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
            return httpRequestFactory; 
    }


    }
```

Response Interceptor

```
public class ResponseInterceptor {

    private HTTPInputProperties inputProperties;
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ResponseInterceptor.class);

    /**
     * Intercepts the errorMessage from the API response and sends appropriate
     * information to the Output channel.
     * 
     * @param errorMessage
     * @return Message
     */
    public Message<String> transform(Message<MessagingException> errorMessage) {

        LOGGER.error("Inside Response Interceptor !");
        Message<String> responseMessage = null;
        try {
            if (null != errorMessage && null != errorMessage.getPayload()
                    && null != errorMessage.getPayload().getCause()) {
                LOGGER.error("Cause is - " + errorMessage.getPayload().getCause().getMessage());
                if (errorMessage.getPayload().getCause() instanceof HttpClientErrorException) {

                    HttpClientErrorException clientError = (HttpClientErrorException) errorMessage.getPayload()
                            .getCause();
                    LOGGER.error("Error in ResponseInceptor", clientError);
                    List<String> errorCodeList = getErrorCodes(inputProperties.getNonRetryErrorCodes());
                    // intercept Only those errors that are defined as
                    // nonRetryErrorCodes options in stream definition
                    if (null != clientError.getStatusCode()
                            && errorCodeList.contains(clientError.getStatusCode().toString())) {

                        LOGGER.error("Error in Response Body", clientError.getResponseBodyAsString());
                        LOGGER.debug("Non retry message found. Sending to output channel without retrying");

                        responseMessage = MessageBuilder.withPayload((null == clientError.getResponseBodyAsString() || clientError.getResponseBodyAsString().isEmpty()) 
                                ? getDefaultPayload(clientError.getStatusCode().toString()) : clientError.getResponseBodyAsString())
                                .setHeader(BatchHttpClientConstants.HTTP_STATUS, clientError.getStatusCode().toString())
                                .setHeader(BatchHttpClientConstants.REQUEST_OBJECT,
                                        getFailedMessagePayload(errorMessage))
                                .copyHeaders(errorMessage.getPayload().getFailedMessage().getHeaders())
                                .setReplyChannelName(BatchHttpClientConstants.OUTPUT).setErrorChannelName(null).build();

                    } else {
                        LOGGER.debug("Status code from API is not present in the nonRetryCodes");
                    }
                } else if (errorMessage.getPayload().getCause() instanceof HttpServerErrorException) {

                    LOGGER.error("Error is Instance of HttpServerErrorException");
                    HttpServerErrorException serverError = (HttpServerErrorException) errorMessage.getPayload()
                            .getCause();

                    responseMessage = MessageBuilder
                            .withPayload((null == serverError.getResponseBodyAsString()
                            || serverError.getResponseBodyAsString().isEmpty())
                            ? getDefaultPayload(serverError.getStatusCode().toString())
                            : serverError.getResponseBodyAsString())
                            .setHeader(BatchHttpClientConstants.HTTP_STATUS, serverError.getStatusCode().toString())
                            .setHeader(BatchHttpClientConstants.REQUEST_OBJECT, getFailedMessagePayload(errorMessage))
                            .copyHeaders(errorMessage.getPayload().getFailedMessage().getHeaders())
                            .setReplyChannelName(BatchHttpClientConstants.OUTPUT).setErrorChannelName(null).build();


                }

            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception occured while transforming errorResponse", exception);
        }

        // returning null will send the message back to previous module
        return responseMessage;
    }

    private String getDefaultPayload(String httpStatusCode) {

        JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();
        if (BatchHttpClientConstants.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.equalsIgnoreCase(httpStatusCode)) {
            jsonResponse.put(BatchHttpClientConstants.ID, BatchHttpClientConstants.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_SUBCODE);
            jsonResponse.put(BatchHttpClientConstants.TEXT, "Internal Server Error");
        } else if (BatchHttpClientConstants.RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND.equalsIgnoreCase(httpStatusCode)) {
            jsonResponse.put(BatchHttpClientConstants.ID, BatchHttpClientConstants.RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND_SUBCODE);
            jsonResponse.put(BatchHttpClientConstants.TEXT, "Empty Response From the API");
        }else{
            jsonResponse.put(BatchHttpClientConstants.ID, BatchHttpClientConstants.GENERIC_ERROR_SUBCODE);
            jsonResponse.put(BatchHttpClientConstants.TEXT, "Generic Error Occured.");
        }

        return jsonResponse.toString();

    }

    /**
     * Get Individual error codes using delimiter
     * 
     * @param nonRetryErrorCodes
     * @return List of Error Codes as string
     */
    private List<String> getErrorCodes(String nonRetryErrorCodes) {

        List<String> errorCodeList = new ArrayList<String>();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(nonRetryErrorCodes, BatchHttpClientConstants.DELIMITER);
        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            errorCodeList.add(st.nextToken());
        }
        return errorCodeList;
    }

    /**
     * returns failed Message Payload
     * 
     * @param errorMessage
     * @return String
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     */
    private byte[] getFailedMessagePayload(Message<MessagingException> errorMessage)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        if (null != errorMessage.getPayload().getFailedMessage()
                && null != errorMessage.getPayload().getFailedMessage().getPayload()) {
            return errorMessage.getPayload().getFailedMessage().getPayload().toString()
                    .getBytes(BatchHttpClientConstants.UTF_8);
        }

        return "".getBytes(BatchHttpClientConstants.UTF_8);
    }

    public HTTPInputProperties getInputProperties() {
        return inputProperties;
    }

    public void setInputProperties(HTTPInputProperties inputProperties) {
        this.inputProperties = inputProperties;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend an `<aggregator>` as a diagnostic tool.

1. Send the message to the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>` (or even better in the beginning of your flow - on `input` channel).
2. And send that message to the `<aggregator>`, too.
3. Some `key` from the message should be used as a `correlationKey`.
4. Expect `reply` from HTTP Gateway as a second message in group to release.
5. The `ReleaseStrategy` is standard `MessageCountReleaseStrategy` based on the `size = 2`.
6. And here is the main trick of the `<aggregator>` - `group-timeout`, which should be a bit more than `socket timeout`. The "uncompleted" group (only request) should be discarded to some other channel, where you will be able to report those undelivered messages and consult with your REST Service what's going on with them.

Comment: some updates after more debugging http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787785/spring-xd-loosing-messages-when-processing-huge-volume

Comment: this helped  thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35787785/spring-xd-loosing-messages-when-processing-huge-volume/35819392?noredirect=1#comment59309729_35819392